# Multimedia PDF viewer for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf, multimedia, pdf-viewer

I want to implement an iOS application which views PDF files. I have used [vfr/Reader](https://github.com/vfr/Reader) in some other applications before. But now i need to display multimedia supported PDF files on iOS which include videos, animations etc. My customer create these PDFs by using InDesign.

I made a research and can not found a proper iOS based framework to achieve this. There are really limited number of solutions like Adobe, FastPDFKit etc but they are so expensive and there is no "one time fee" option.

Do you have any open source suggestions or the ones with lower prices?

EDIT: Made a research for days and days but there is no solution. Is there any other tool to create interactive ebooks or magazines? May be HTML5 or something with editor itself???

Comment: Can you view those PDF's on iOS? (ie. via Safari?) If so try viewing them via WebView.

Comment: unfortunately you can not ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long long research and discussions, unfortunately there is no free solution with these  features. There are only paid solutions and Adobe Publishing Suite takes the head although it is one of the most expensive solutions

Answer (score 0):

I have used [QLPreviewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) before to open local PDF files and it works great and it not hard to implement-- and it supports multiple documents.

Heres a good tutorial that I followed:
http://mobiledevelopertips.com/data-file-management/preview-documents-with-qlpreviewcontroller.html

I have not tested viewing videos or anything-- the PDFs I had were simple. But it is an Apple control and has all of the basic PDF viewing functions like pinch to zoom, but like I said my PDFs only had text but it is worth a shot to try.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not support multimedia.